# Sylius themes - how to modify event?

Tags: sylius

I'm trying to customize the Sylius theme and I would like to modify the footer.
There are events sylius.shop.layout.footer and sylius.shop.layout.footer.grid.
In config, the sylius.shop.layout.footer.grid event consists from several blocks:

vendor/sylius/sylius/src/Sylius/Bundle/ShopBundle/Resources/config/app/config.yml

```
        sylius.shop.layout.footer.grid:
            blocks:
                before_legacy:
                    template: "@SyliusUi/Block/_legacySonataEvent.html.twig"
                    priority: 45
                    context:
                        event: sylius.shop.layout.before_footer
                plus:
                    template: "@SyliusShop/Layout/Footer/Grid/_plus.html.twig"
                    priority: 40
                your_store:
                    template: "@SyliusShop/Layout/Footer/Grid/_your_store.html.twig"
                    priority: 30
                customer_care:
                    template: "@SyliusShop/Layout/Footer/Grid/_customer_care.html.twig"
                    priority: 20
                payment_methods:
                    template: "@SyliusShop/Layout/Footer/Grid/_payment_methods.html.twig"
                    priority: 10
```

I need to not render block plus.
How to do it?

I created config file, copied sylius.shop.layout.footer.grid event and commented removed block plus:
config/packages/sylius_ui.yaml

```
sylius_ui:
    events:
        sylius.shop.layout.footer.grid:
            blocks:
                before_legacy:
                    template: "@SyliusUi/Block/_legacySonataEvent.html.twig"
                    priority: 45
                    context:
                        event: sylius.shop.layout.before_footer
                #plus:
                #    template: "@SyliusShop/Layout/Footer/Grid/_plus.html.twig"
                #    priority: 40
                your_store:
                    template: "@SyliusShop/Layout/Footer/Grid/_your_store.html.twig"
                    priority: 30
                customer_care:
                    template: "@SyliusShop/Layout/Footer/Grid/_customer_care.html.twig"
                    priority: 20
                payment_methods:
                    template: "@SyliusShop/Layout/Footer/Grid/_payment_methods.html.twig"
                    priority: 10
```

But template @SyliusShop/Layout/Footer/Grid/_plus.html.twig is still rendered.
How to change or modify from which templates is footer rendered?

Answer (score 0):

You need to set the key to false to not let the block render:

```
sylius_ui:
    events:
         sylius.shop.layout.footer.grid:
              blocks:
                  plus: false
```

Answer (score 0):

in **config/packages/sylius_ui.yaml** it is possible to disable a block, then the block will not rendered

```
 sylius_ui:
        events:
            sylius.shop.layout.footer.grid:
                blocks:
                    plus:
                        enabled: false
```